# Firebase cloud functions admin.messaging.send() is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I created a function in index.js that sends a notification to a user every time they have a new activity feed item like when someone likes a post or leaves a comment or sends a message. When I ran it, I got this error in my function logs on firebase:

```
TypeError: admin.messaging.send is not a function
    at sendNotification (/workspace/index.js:220:8)
    at exports.onCreateActivityFeedItem.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/workspace/index.js:176:5)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I already tried `npm install firebase-admin@latest` but it didn't fix the issue. This is the function I created in index.js

```
exports.onCreateActivityFeedItem = functions.firestore
.document('/feed/{userId}/feedItems/{activityFeedItem}')
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
  console.log('Activity feed item created', snapshot.data());

  // 1) Get user connected to the feed
  const userId = context.params.userId;

  const userRef = admin.firestore().doc(`users/${userId}`);
  const doc = await userRef.get();

  // 2) Once we have user, check if they have a notification token; 
  //send notification if they have token
  const androidNotificationToken = doc.data().androidNotificationToken;
  const createdActivityFeedItem = snapshot.data();
  if (androidNotificationToken) {
    sendNotification(androidNotificationToken, createdActivityFeedItem);
  } else {
    console.log('No token for user, cannot send notification');
  }

  function sendNotification(androidNotificationToken, activityFeedItem){
    let body;

    // 3) switch body based on activity feed item type
    switch (activityFeedItem.type) {
      case 'comment':
        body = `${activityFeedItem.username} replied: 
        ${activityFeedItem.commentData}`;
        break;
        case 'like':
          body = `${activityFeedItem.username} liked your post`;
        break;
        case 'follow':
          body = `${activityFeedItem.username} started following you`;
        break;
        case 'request':
          body = `${activityFeedItem.username} needs a tutorial in ${activityFeedItem.postId}`;
        break;
        case 'accepted':
          body = `${activityFeedItem.username} accepted your 
          ${activityFeedItem.postId} request`;
        break;
        case 'message':
          body = `${activityFeedItem.username} sent you a message`;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    // 4) Create message for push notification
    const message = {
      notification: {body},
      token: androidNotificationToken,
      data: {recipient: userId},
    }

    // 5) Send message with admin.messaging()
    admin
      .messaging
      .send(message)
      .then(response => {
        // response is a message ID string
        console.log('Succesfully sent message', response)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error sending message', error)
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `admin.messaging()` with parenthesis.  It's a function call, not a property, just like you are already using with `admin.firestore()`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. However it's still not displaying any notifications

Comment: Sounds like you have a different problem that's not related to the one you first posted about.  I suggest doing some debugging and post again to describe what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: I posted the rest of my notification implementation

Comment: You should post the new question separately.  Stack Overflow only allows one question or issue per post.  I have reverted **this** post here to its original question, which already has an answer.  Your **new** post should explain in detail what is now not working the way you expect, after you have applied the fix that I described.